# coin change algo using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Give a set of coins and target . Need to print all the solutions possible in a list using recursion.

The solution i have come up with print all the solutions in single list . How do i make it a list of lists ? Please advise.

```
def coin_change(A, target):
    if target in A:
        return [target]
    ll = []
    for i in A:
        if i < target:
            ll = ll + [i] + coin_change(A, target - i) 
        else:
            ll = ll +  [-1]
    return ll

coins = [3,10,7]
target = 5
```

Comment: What is your expected output for your example `coins` and `target` given you cannot make the `target`.

Comment: what is unclear ? if target is not possible empty list ? Not fair to down vote just because its trivial or not clear .

Comment: What is unclear is you claim to print all the solutions in a flattened list but running the code above yields a list of 3 and a lot of -1s. Yet you say this should be a empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are likely different ways to do this, here's one that returns all potential results, even duplicates, in a hopefully understandable list structure of alternate solutions:

```
def coin_change(coins, target):
    ''' returns a list of lists of alternate solutions '''

    if target in coins:
        return [[target]]  # only one possibility, base case

    possibilities = []

    for coin in coins:
        if coin < target:
            possibilities += [[coin, *possibility] for possibility in coin_change(coins, target - coin)]

    return possibilities

print(coin_change([5, 10, 25], 30))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[5, 25], [10, 5, 5, 10], [10, 5, 10, 5], [10, 10, 10], [25, 5]]
```

In the case of no solution, it should return the empty list.

Comment: Note the OP's solution, and this one, don't return "all the solutions possible" since the `if target in coins:` test keeps a solution like, "all nickels" from being considered.  But this question was primarily about data format. not about optimal nor complete solutions.

Comment: yeah fair enough . Thanks for that .